# Convert vb.net shell to c#

Tags: c#

I used this code to create a scheduled task in vb.net, now I'm learning C# and want to make this code to work with C#:

```
`Shell("schtasks.exe /create /TN " & ChrW(34) & "Updataas\AAMyname task" & ChrW(34) & " /XML " & ChrW(34) & path & ChrW(34))`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [**`Process.Start`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Process.Start("schtasks.exe", "/create /TN \"Updataas\\AAMyname task\" /XML \"" + path + "\"");
```

Comment: @Mujahedqassamy What do you mean by didn't work? What was the error? Why didn't it work?

Comment: when i execute vb.net code it's add the task successfully , i cant do it with c#

Comment: problem that's no error code executed with no error but the task isn't created